# Destructuring and Redefining react prop

Tags: reactjs

I've got a chunk of code at work that is behaving poorly and I am trying to figure out why. In the course of doing that, I came across something like the code below and I have some questions.

A functional component ...

```
const myComp = ({propName1, propName2: myVar = false})=>{
    ...
    const propName2=true;
    ...
}
```

I'm not totally sure what's happening with propName2 here. If there was just an "=false", then this would be establishing a default value, but that isn't what's happening. myVar is a variable that may be present as a prop. Is it simply setting the default value to that prop if it is present and false if not?

Second, why doesn't react produce an error when the code redefines the prop to a const?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This syntax is assigning `propName2` prop to a `myVar` variable in the context.

This is roughly the same code:

```js
const MyComp = (props) => {
    let myVar = props.propName2;
    const propName2=true;
    ...
}
```

…so: this is why you don't get any error by defining `propName2`: it does not exists.

## Why this is useful

Renaming variables while destructuring saves you some lines of code and can make it more readable.

A couple of examples

In a React context you receive props named following the component public interface (like `url`) but internally your "url" can be more complex:

```js
const MyComp = ({ url: baseURL }) => {
    const url = baseURL + '/foo/bar/baz';
    // now you can fetch(url)
    ...
}
```

Another common issue: you spread properties from a JSON source that can be in a `snake_case_var` while your code style can be a canonical JavaScript `camelCaseVar`.

```js
const MyComp = ({ snake_case_var: camelCaseVar }) => {
    ...
}
```

Last but not least: you can spread and rename deeply nested properties without polluting the scope with additional data:

```js
const MyComp = ({ params: { search_query: searchQuery } }) => {
    console.log(searchQuery);
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks. That's what I was suspecting, but I don't understand the reason for doing this?

Comment: Updated the answer a little